# Mongo .Net Driver PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Project automatically ignores all Id values with a facet

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

When using the PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder when creating projection stages for an aggregation pipeline it appears to be always ignoring any `Id` values in the dataset. I'm using the Mongo .Net driver 2.8 in a .Net Core app. Below are the steps for reproduction.

The same projection worked when using the IAggregateFluent syntax on Aggregate() however I needed to use the builders for a facet. When running the builder against Aggregate it also works, however within a `facet` it fails to bind any `Id` values.

Just empty classes with id for testing (Added Type to show normal mapping works):

```
public class DatabaseModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectionClass
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

When I create the projection with the below, it produces a query sucessfully, however within all models returned the Id value is set to null. The query seems to have a Id_ : 0 value but the same also seems to be produced in normal aggregation so I don't think this is related?

```
var typeFilter = Builders<DatabaseModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Type, "Full");

var aggregationPipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<DatabaseModel>()
    .AppendStage(PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(typeFilter))
    .AppendStage(PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Project<DatabaseModel, ProjectionClass>(x => new ProjectionClass
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Type = x.Type,
    }));

var normalAggregationResult = await db.Aggregate(aggregationPipeline).ToListAsync();//The id's appear here

var databaseModelsFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("DatabaseModels", aggregationPipeline);
var faucetResult = db.Aggregate().Facet(databaseModelsFacet).SingleOrDefault().Facets;

var projectionModels = faucetResult.
    Single(x => x.Name == "DatabaseModels")
    .Output<ProjectionClass>();// This results in missing Id's (Including in nested objects with anything named Id)
```

Resulting mongo query

```
{[{ 
    "$match" : { "Type" : "Full" } }, 
  { "$project" : { "Id" : "$_id", "Type" : "$Type", "_id" : 0 } 
}]}
```

Is there any way to be able to run a projection using the pipeline builders with a facet while not ignoring the Id? I have seen examples using similar queries but haven't seen this as an issue. It could be an issue with facet as it only appears to happen when using this.

Thanks!

UPDATE 6/1/2020: Updated question after finding it only seems to occur with facet

Comment: Do you need to get _id form MongoDB and change it to Id? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I’m just looking to project the id with my projection - in a larger example it projects all fields fine but always adds the _id :0 to the resulting query leading to any identifier fields in the returned aggregation to be null

Comment: Could you please show the result that you get from Mongodb?

Comment: Hi @MohammadTaherian I've updated the question as it only seems to be occuring when i pass the pipeline into a facet, hope this is more clear.

Comment: @Josh I'm running into the same issue.. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an Driver issue, (or other issue is when the structure does not match the fields), as Id cant simply be serialized to Id , but if you choose any other value it will work for example

```
[BsonNoId]
public class DatabaseModel
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```